# Knockout SelectedOptions binding to property of object fails

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I am having trouble with a knockout `options` binding, specifically a multi select with `selectedOptions` mapping to a property of a `ko.observable` Here is the html:

```
<select data-bind="options: disabilities, optionsValue: 'id', selectedOptions: 'currentBusType().disabilities', optionsText: 'code'" multiple="true" size="5"></select>
```

`disabilities` is an `ko.observableArray` with the following structure:

```
[
  {"id":"1","code":"WC","description":"Wheel Chair"},
  {"id":"2","code":"SN","description":"Special Needs"}
]
```

`currentBusType` is a `ko.observable` with the following structure:

```
{
  "bustype_id":"2",
  "name":"Bus Type 2",
  "capacity":"20",
  "serial_number":null,
  "disabilities":[1,2]
}
```

The result is, according to an inspection of the DOM, a multiselect that has values and options correct but does not properly preselect the options. How should I be doing this binding and what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `selectedOptions: 'currentBusType().disabilities'` should be `selectedOptions: currentBusType().disabilities` (remove the `'`)

Comment: I had already tried that. So its looks like this: `selectedOptions: 'currentBusType.disabilities'` This exhibits the same behaviour (ie breaks in the same way)

Comment: That's not what I meant. I just meant that you need to remove the single quotes surround your expression: `selectedOptions: currentBusType().disabilities`

Comment: Ok, tried the following `selectedOptions: currentBusType().disabilities` same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to remove the single quotes surrounding your expression:

```
selectedOptions: currentBusType().disabilities
```

Then you need to make sure the types of the each disability `id` matches those in your `currentBusType.disabilities`. Currently, one is a `Number` and the other is `String`. So, if you change `disabilities`, it would look like:

```
"disabilities": ["1", "2"]
```

See [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c7at99gy/1/)

Comment: this string/int thing was what I was missing. Thanks!